# Is it possible that a person can do sin without knowing?

Tags: sin

Are all sins committed by a person fully knowing ?
Isa person saying that he committed sin not knowing or out of ignorance false pretence ?

For example - Suppose a person steps on some ants on the floor and kills the ants and he takes the excuse that he didn't see the insects on the floor but truth is he walked carelessly so the ants got killed.

Note - I just gave an example of sin. Here I am not judging if killing of ants is big sin or small sin.

Comment: Yes, it's possible and you have proved  by giving example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as soon as you come in this world, your karma starts pilling up. Even if a person chose to be inactive and stay in bed, such a person by breathing is killing various micro-organism present in air.

So there is no escape in general sense. Jivo Jivasya Jivanam, One life is food for another.

The way to break this vicious cycle is to surrender your life and activities to God.
Just like if you join armed forces and you kill your enemy, you don't have to go to jail. Because you have surrendered your life to the Nation.
similarly when you join with God, follow his instruction, work for him, he takes care of your karmic reactions

sarva-dharmān parityajya mām ekaṁ śharaṇaṁ vraja
ahaṁ tvāṁ sarva-pāpebhyo mokṣhayiṣhyāmi mā śhuchaḥ

BG 18.66: Abandon all varieties of dharmas and simply surrender unto Me alone. I shall liberate you from all sinful reactions; do not fear.